# Using node-thumbnail to generate thumbnail from image

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I am trying to generate a thumbnail from image using node-thumbnail, the thumbnail is being uploaded to my container in azure storage but it looks like the original file not like a thumbnail. Here's my code, first I am uploading the original image, then reading it and generating a thumbnail from it, then uploading the thumbnail to container. What am I doing wrong? I couldn't find much resources online on how to do this, please help!

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
if (!req.files)
  return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

// The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
let name = sampleFile.name;
let data = sampleFile.data;
//var options = { contentSettings: { contentType: 'image/jpeg' } }

blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromText('test-container', name, data, function(error, result, response){
    if (error){
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Uploaded to container');
    }


    var info = blobSvc.getBlobToLocalFile ("test-container", name, name,
        function (error, blockBlob, response) {
            thumb({
                source: name, // could be a filename: dest/path/image.jpg
                destination: './',
                concurrency: 4,
                width: 100
              }, function(files, err){
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("resized");
                //Delete the downloaded BIG one


                //Upload the thumbnail
                blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile("test-container", files[0].dstPath, files[0].dstPath,
                function (error, blockBlob, response) {
                    if (!error) {
                        console.log("thumbnail uploaded: " + name);

                    } else{
                        console.log(error);
                    }

                });
            });
        });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an Azure Storage issue, it's more of a `node-thumbnail` issue.

How about using [`Jimp`](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp#jimp):

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var Jimp = require("jimp");
var path = require('path');

// ...

var info = blobSvc.getBlobToLocalFile("test-container", name, name, function(error, blockBlob, response) {

    if (!error) {

        var dstName = path.parse(name).name + "_thumb" + path.parse(name).ext;

        Jimp.read(name, function(err, image) {

            if (err) throw err;
            image.resize(100, Jimp.AUTO)             // resize
                .quality(60)                         // set JPEG quality
                .write(dstName, function(err, ret) { // save

                    //Upload the thumbnail
                    blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile("test-container", dstName, dstName, function(error, blockBlob, response) {
                        if (!error) {
                            console.log("thumbnail uploaded: " + dstName);
                        } else {
                            console.log(error);
                        }

                    });
                });
        });
    }
});
```